# Help with a nasty sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need help with the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \binom{k}{n}-k \left \lfloor{\frac{\binom{k}{n}}{k} } \right \rfloor$$

I've found that the sum is equivalent to the following: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \binom{k}{n} \mod k$$
But I can't find a closed form for the life of me. Even in terms of special functions, is there a closed form for this sum?

Comment: Does it help that $_kC_n \mod k$ is $0$ when $k$ is prime?

Comment: Substitute $x=1$ in the Binomial Theorem expansion of $(1+x)^{k}$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz What exactly do you want me to clarify?

Comment: As @ancientmathematician commented, why not use Binomial theorem? It is $2^k -1$ mod $k$.